# How many Fate points do NPCs have in an encounter?

Tags: fate-core, fate-points

I remember reading somewhere in the core rulebook how many fate points NPCs ought to have in an encounter, but I can't find it now.

So, where can I see how many fate points I should give my NPCs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find those rules in the Aspects & Fate Points chapter, under *The Fate Point Economy.* Page 82 of the book mentions *the GM and Fate Points*. You can read it [here](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/fate-point-economy#the-abbr-title-game-master-gm-abbr-and-fate-points) on the Fate SRD.

In short: the GM starts with one fate point per PC in the encounter. As the GM, all your NPCs collectively tap into that (small) fate point pool.